# nested vm failed to boot with "KVM: entry failed, hardware error 0x0"

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Trying to create a nested vm with `virt-manager`. vm stuck at paused state.

From instance log under `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/`, I see following errors. Anyway to get around this?

```
KVM: entry failed, hardware error 0x0
EAX=00000000 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000663
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000000
EIP=0000fff0 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
CS =f000 ffff0000 0000ffff 00009b00
SS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
DS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
FS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
GS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 0000ffff
IDT=     00000000 0000ffff
CR0=60000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
EFER=0000000000000000
Code=00 66 89 d8 66 e8 02 f7 ff ff 66 83 c4 0c 66 5b 66 5e 66 c3 <ea> 5b e0 00 f0 30 36 2f 32 33 2f 39 39 00 fc 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Host OS (VM): Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

```
lab@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -l | egrep "qemu-kvm|libvirt"

ii  libvirt-bin                         1.2.2-0ubuntu13.1.14                  amd64        programs for the libvirt library
ii  libvirt0                            1.2.2-0ubuntu13.1.14                  amd64        library for interfacing with different virtualization systems
ii  python-libvirt                      1.2.2-0ubuntu2                        amd64        libvirt Python bindings
ii  qemu-kvm                            2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.19                amd64        QEMU Full virtualization
```

Host OS: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz

```
lab@HP-GEN9:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                48
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-47
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    12
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 63
Stepping:              2
CPU MHz:               1200.000
BogoMIPS:              5195.56
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              30720K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-11,24-35
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     12-23,36-47
```

and

```
lab@HP-GEN9:~$ cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested
Y
```

BTW, I followed the steps listed at http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_14.04&p=kvm&f=8

lab@HP-GEN9:~$ virsh capabilities | egrep "model|vendor"
      SandyBridge
      Intel
    
      apparmor
    
    
      dac

lab@HP-GEN9:~$ virsh capabilities | egrep "model|vendor|vmx"
      SandyBridge
      Intel
      
    
      apparmor
    
    
      dac

Comment: BTW, I followed the steps listed at http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_14.04&p=kvm&f=8

Comment: I'm not sure how to help you, as I do not use virt-manager. I have done nested VM's (14.04.3 server host - 15.10 server VM - 15.10 server vm-vm) and didn't have any troubles doing so.